# How to change devise views model in an existing app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

So, I have actually generated the views for devise but recently i want to change it back to another name, how will i?

Initially it was rails g devise 'Writer'...
now, i want rails g devise 'User'

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Destroy and then generate the model.

First:

```
 rails destroy devise Writer
```

then:

```
rails generate devise User
```

It would be more easier and recommended then changing.

Answer (score 0):

if you cannot destroy your devise model then one method is to

rename occurrences of user_signed_in?,  current_user, user_session
(see [devise helpers](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#controller-filters-and-helpers))

Rename your db table name (migration), modify your tests files, model and route to **devise_for :users**.

Answer (score 0):

Everything now works fine. I deleted the writer's column from the database and generated another one.